# Table width is longer then the pixels specified?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

Here is my html but when I measure the last td its way longer then 300px...any idea?

```
<table width='400'>
    <tr>
        <th colspan='2' style='text-align:left;'><br /><br />Beginner<br /><br /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>another Deal</th>

      <th>Users</th>

    </tr>
  <tr>  
    <td>SomeDat</td>
    <td>0/38</td>
    <td style="width:300px">
        <span class="red"></span> <span class="yellow"></span></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>  
    <td>Git</td>
    <td>28/38</td>
    <td style="width:300px">
        <span class="red">something,something,something,something,something,something,something,something,something,something,something,    ,something,something,something,something,something</span> <span class="yellow">test</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table will expand to the width needed for its widest element.  "something,something,..." is a very long unbreakable word, and is forcing your table wider than you want it.

If you add spaces, the text will wrap.  If you want to clip long unbreakable words, try `overflow:hidden` in the style.

Comment: thanks for reminding me of this, I had a text input with the "size" attribute set too large for the table. removing it made the whole thing pretty again thanks @Ned

Answer (score 5):

As Ned said, the long word is causing the cell to expand.

You can partially solve this by adding `word-wrap: break-word;` to the style attribute of the table cell. This will cause the word to break when it reaches the limits of the table cell. Fully supported in IE and any CSS3-supporting browsers.

Comment: better than overflow:hidden because nothing will go missing. boom!