# <td>s are larger than specified

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need my table cells have `100px` width, but instead they have `112px` width (`112` in chrome, `113` in FF, `112.5` in IE10).

There is *more than enough* space inside:

[image: tiny screenshot]

And these are styles applied to `td`
[image: styles]

Piece of html:

```
<tr>
    <td class = 'col_body_dates'>12.12.2013<br/>20.12.2013</td>
    <td class='col_body_status cell_status_1'>в процессе</td>
    <td class='col_body_score'><input id = '7623373922438661459' value = '0'></td>
    ...
    ...
</tr>
```

How do I make them desired size? **Differences between css and real size are always the same**...

What am I missing?

Ah yes, I tried :

- [Table width is longer then the pixels specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936271/table-width-is-longer-then-the-pixels-specified)
- [Why is browser showing td's larger than my specified width property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026000/why-is-browser-showing-tds-larger-than-my-specified-width-property)

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/3hFk7/

Comment: Please post your CSS instead of a chrome dump too please.  Right off the bat it looks like a td border issue.

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net` is what he means -> http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: my guess is that in some other cell in the same column you have something that is forcing the cell to outgrow its stated width. being a table all cells in the column then grow to the width of the widest. try wrapping the content of each cell in a div with width 100px overflow hidden.

Comment: here : http://jsfiddle.net/3hFk7/

Answer (score 11):

Your table is not a fixed width. Cells will always automatically resize themselves to accommodate the width of the entire table.

Unless you apply:

```
table{
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

You can set the width of a column only if the sum of the columns equal the total width of the table.

Manually set column widths on the table using column grouping:

```
  <colgroup>
     <col span="1" style="width: 100px;">
     <col span="1" style="width: 100px;">
     <col span="1" style="width: 100px;">
  </colgroup>
```

**NOTE:** Use **style** not **width** as width is depreciated in HTML5 and ideally set styles in CSS instead of inline.

---

### Cellspacing and Cellpadding

**If you do not specify a value the default value designated by the users browser will be used. This is not always 0 when it comes to tables.**

If you **default cellspacing and cellpadding on your table** then you can control the padding of each cell in css using the padding attribute:

**CSS**

```
th,td {
  padding:5px
}
```

---

### Precedence of non-CSS presentational hints in the CSS 2.1

> **Spec says:** “The UA may choose to honor presentational attributes in an HTML source document. If so, these attributes are translated to
> the corresponding CSS rules with specificity equal to 0, and are
> treated as if they were inserted at the start of the author style
> sheet. They may therefore be overridden by subsequent style sheet
> rules.”

So any relevant setting in any author style sheet being applied overrides the effect of cellspacing. The attribute sets the padding (in each direction) for each cell of the table to the specified value in pixels. So if you set e.g. for a particular cell padding-right: 0, it will have that right padding and 4px padding in other directions.

---

Table with cellpadding and cellpadding:

```
<table cellpadding="10" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <th>Head 1</th>
    <th>Head 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Note:** The cellpadding attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zb8kR/

Comment: table-layout:fixed will not prevent the layout from expanding as there is in the third column a input element which has no style appied on it. It will make the table larger. See http://jsfiddle.net/JYKLf/1/ (with text in third col) vs http://jsfiddle.net/6MFgv/1/ (with input)

Comment: @Sigma you are correct but this is not what I said. I stated "Cells will always automatically resize themselves to accommodate the width of the entire table. Unless you apply table-layout:fixed" So was the mark down necessary? I was simply offering an explanation why cells don't always become the size you specify.

Comment: It seems to work with text in table cells but not with inputs like in the example. The inputs will expand the table cells none the less.

Comment: You still haven't explained why the downvote? Setting column width as in my answer will resolve the op's issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` to zero, also remove default margins and paddings:

**HTML**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4eAVq/)**

Comment: You can do table {border-collapse; collapse;} which is the CSS equivalent of <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

Answer (score 0):

To define the width of the columns you can use the col tag.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp

It will apply the width on all tds of that column. In this case that would be 100px on the first two columns. And the width will be minimum 100px or more depending on the content.
Also when you would set padding on the TD it still will add up to 100px per column.

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col id='col_body_dates'>
    <col id='col_hdr_dates'>
    <col />
  </colgroup>
 <tr>
 [...]

 #col_body_dates, 
 #col_hdr_dates {
  width: 100px;
}

table { 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
 #col_body_dates, 
 #col_hdr_dates {
  width: 100px;
}
td {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vxsPL/53/